# I am having issues with an external JS file

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. I have an external js file linked to a page, but its just not working. I don't know the line i went wrong in the js file. Help, please

```js
function show_alert()
{
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Show alert box" />
```

This is the code i used to link the file

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="js\popup.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: How did you imported your js file ? Make sure to include it in the head tag.

Comment: What do you mean by "just not working"? Like, it's not doing anything? If your JS file is linked as you say it is, then post the code you used to link it. If what you posted is straight from your HTML file, then you need to surround your JavaScript with <script> tags, otherwise your function will be parsed as HTML instead of as JS.

Comment: And what errors do you get?

Comment: You should be exporting your function so that it's accessible to other classes.
`export function ...`.

Comment: As you can see, here in the snippet it works, so probably your problem is with the import of your js file. How are you doing it?

Comment: This is the code i used to link the file  <head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="js\popup.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: This is the code i used to link the file <head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="js\popup.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: Only thing I can think of would be to flip that backslash to a forward slash.

Comment: is the folder `js` and your html page under the same directory ? and you shoud write `js/popup.js` and not `js\popup.js`

Comment: Yes they are in the same directory, and i also flipped the backslash. still not working

Answer (score 0):

First check the console in the Developer tools of your browser for any errors ( use F12 or Ctrl + Shift + I to open dev tools). If there's no error in the console, then check if the file path you stated is present in the directory you are.